# What are the limitations (durations + maximum data use) of the free Wi-Fi at Yangon International Airport (RNG)?

Tags: airports, wifi, myanmar, yangon, rgn

Yangon International Airport (RNG) offers free Wi-Fi (SSID: Wifi@YIA, Wifi@YIA2 and Wifi@YIA3 depending on whether one is located in terminal 1, 2 or 3 a.k.a. domestic)

What are the limitations (durations + maximum data use) of the free Wi-Fi at [Yangon International Airport (RNG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yangon_International_Airport)?

Answer (score 3):

From [travelbriefs](https://www.thetravelbrief.com/briefs/yangon-international-airport-free-public-wifi-available-at-yangon-international-airport) in March 2019:

> The network is called Wifi@YIA and it's available for anyone to use without password
>
> The speed was actually pretty decent, enough for regular browsing purposes
>
> I can't remember the details but I'm pretty sure there wasn't any time limit on it either